# Dragon Naturally Speaking slows down entire Windows system

Tags: dragon-naturally-speaking

My wife recently installed Dragon Naturally Speaking Premium 13 on her Windows 8 system (Intel processor, 2 cores, 4 logical processors, 6 GB memory, 24 GB SSD, 750 GB disk about half full). She also has Dragon 12.5 on an older Windows 7 machine (3 GB memory, not sure about other statistics).

Since she installed Dragon on the fast machine, it is often unresponsive for long periods of time, even when Task Manager shows free memory and light CPU load. Since she reinstalled the older Dragon on the slower machine, it is often unresponsive for even longer -- sometimes ten seconds to do simple things (changing tabs in Chrome, for example, even when she has only a few tabs open). The only changes she can think of are the Dragon installations.

The slow response time happens whether Dragon has been explicitly activated or not; my best guess is that Dragon has background tasks that intermittently hog the system.

Is there a way to disable background Dragon tasks so they don't randomly slow down a Windows system, and reactivate it when she actually wants to use voice to text? Ideally, it would be something she could do with a Dragon control panel, to shut it down gracefully and reactivate it completely. But if that's not possible, she'd like to know which process (or processes) to kill with Task Manager, and the best way to reactivate Dragon when she wants to use it. (If killing background processes really confuses Dragon, a reboot might be the only way to get it working again; if that's the case, a reboot is an acceptable solution.)

Comment: Hopefully you will get a good answer here, but if not, give the KnowBrainer forum a try.  That forum has died-in-the-wool Dragon experts and they respond quickly.

Comment: "Since she reinstalled the older Dragon on the slower machine, it is often unresponsive for even longer..." implies that she did not **uninstall** one version of DNS before installing the other. Try removing *both*, then just install one.

Comment: @DrMoishe Pippik -- What I meant was that she removed Dragon 12.5 from the older machine (with the uninstaller, I'm pretty sure), then put it back after freeing up disk space. It worked adequately when it was explicitly activated, but made the whole machine slow when she tried to do anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sept 29, 2022 - Installed latest Dragon Nat (15.61.200.010) on a new laptop with an i7-12700H proc, 16GB RAM and a 512 GB SSD HD. This was a fast system that bogged down to a crawl when Dragon Nat was running. I had some frustration with Nuance support, as their first level teams were unhelpful, and it was only after I asked to speak with second-level support that I received a solution that actually worked. This is what they told me to do:

Restoring to the Original Sept 29th profile and then also creating a new user profile did not fix the problem. I was using the new user Profile when implementing the fix so it could possibly be part of the solution.

While using the new user profile:

On Dragon Bar
Open Administrative Settings, Choose Proceed (it will close the user profile)
Choose Scheduled Tasks - uncheck items.

On Dragon Bar
Open Tools, Options
Data - uncheck Store Corrections In Archive.

In Windows File Explorer, enter path %temp%
Clear/Delete Contents of the User Temp Folder.

Reboot System.

Excel, Outlook, Chrome... went from taking 13 sec or longer to immediately opening.

Comment: Belated thanks for a good answer! Speech-to-text on phones has advanced in the years since the original question, but if she uses Dragon again I'll definitely have a useful solution available.